# Using regex in scrapy downolader middleware

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I've been trying to make a custom middleware in Scrapy, which will flag urls containing certain patterns using regex. In short, there is a list of exceptions, and each url is checked against it. However, the middleware does not manage to properly identify the exceptions (it always returns a None result for re.match()).

I've tried implementing regex in a separate script, and it works. I'd really appreciate any ideas as to why this may be happening.

Here is the example situation:

1)Spider

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class AmazonSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'amazon'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://amazon.co.uk/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=''), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = {}
        i['url'] = response.url
        return i
```

2)Settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'foo'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['foo.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'foo.spiders'

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'foo.middlewares.FooDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'foo.middlewares.TryMiddleware':500,
}
```

3)my middleware(i.e. a new class in middlewares.py):

```
import logging
import re
```

.
.
.

```
class TryMiddleware(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.items_scraped = 0
    self.target = ''
    self.exceptions = []

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    s = cls()

    return s

def process_request(self, request, spider):
    self.target = str(request)

    # Just an example, at a later stage, these will be dynamically generated.
    self.exceptions = ['Audible-Audiobook-Downloads','help']

    for i in self.exceptions:
        pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z0-9.:/-]+/{}/[0-9a-z.:/-]+'.format(re.escape(i)))

        if i in self.target:
            m = pattern.match(self.target)
            # This is how I tried checking if the word is contained in the url,
            # and see if regex caught it.
            logger.info(f'\n*\nFound {m} in {target}\n*\n')

    return None
```

4)This is an example of what my logger identifies:

*
Found None in https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cookies_notice?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201890250>
*

Answer (score 2):

Your code *does* work, you're trying to match `Audible-Audiobook-Downloads`, which returns `None` for the url in your question since it does not exist, *that's* what you're seeing. Then it goes to check if `help` exists in the url, which it does and it does already print that.

In the code below I check if `m` is *not* `None` and then print the full match.

```
import logging
import re

exceptions = ['Audible-Audiobook-Downloads','help']

for i in exceptions:
    pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z0-9.:/-]+/{}/[0-9a-z.:/-]+'.format(re.escape(i)))

    m = pattern.match("https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=footer_cookies_notice?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201890250")
    if m:
        print(m.group(0))
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the advice. That's the thing, when I check regex in a separate script, like the one you provided, all works well. But when I implement it in middleware is when the problem occurs. Am I maybe making a mistake in how I refer to the request url? Also, I am using Python 3.7, but have also tried running the code in 3.5.3 (changed f'' to .format()), but the results are the same.